# Error importing both google visions and storage

Tags: spring-boot, maven, google-cloud-platform, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am using spring boot, and cannot get both google storage and Vision to import. I currently have `com.google.cloud.spring.storage.*;`
but as for visions, `com.google.cloud.visions` or `com.google.cloud.spring.visions` do not exist. How do I properly add my pom.xml so that I have both visions and google storage?

...

```
<properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
            <spring-cloud-gcp.version>3.2.0</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
            <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-vision</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                  <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
                  <type>pom</type>
                  <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                  <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                  <version>25.1.0</version>
                  <type>pom</type>
                  <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

also here is a whole bunch of filler text, because stackoverflow wont let me post because it thinks most of this post is code, and not enough details are here :)

Comment: Don't you want `org.springframework.cloud` as the `groupId` for `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage`? [Spring Cloud GCP](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gcp)

Comment: In your question, it would be useful if you describe the error that you're receiving. I agree with the bot that your question contains insufficient detail.

Comment: Got it! I had the wrong group id :)

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @DazWilkin,
according to the content of the file that you have provided, the group_id for the **spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage** is **org.springframework.cloud**. **Groupid** is the distinct identification for a project using which a project can be uniquely identified across all projects.